# Lazy load @EnableCaching class in spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, lazy-loading, spring-annotations

I want my spring boot server to be up even if my redis cache isnt up.

I am using `@EnableCaching`annotation , but my server startup fails if redis is down giving me `BeanCreationException`. Because `BeanCreationException` cannot be handled , the only option I have is to lazy load my `@EnableCaching` class.

I tried annotating that class as under:

```
@Configuration
@EnableCaching
@Lazy
@Profile("dev")
public class RedisCache extends CachingConfigurerSupport {}
```

But still this bean is getting loaded at server startup and startup therefore fails.

How do I lazy load the above mentioned class

Comment: what do you intend with lazy-load? based on what?

Comment: lazy load always ... the intention as mentioned in the question is that if beancreation fails then I want to handle the same. Spring doesnt directly allow to handle beancreation exception while startup(try catch on Exception wont work)

Comment: You should be able to startup even if Redis is not. Could you show us more details about what your config looks like? Strip the details. Please also post the full stacktrace.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know Spring configuration is alwasy loaded on application startup, because that is when the ApplicationContext is created.

In order to do what you want you'd either have to create some sort of custom implementation of ApplicationContext (although I honestly cannot think of how it should work regarding the dependency resolution for dependency injection) or create custom wrapper for caching which would not try to establish connection to Redis until the cache is used.

It may also be possible to configure Spring Boot to skip this particular @Configuration class ([Using Boot configuration classes](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-configuration-classes.html)) and then to manually create [AnnotationConfigApplicationContext](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.html) and then retrieve Redis connection Beans from this context manually rather than autowiring them.